# Cannot delete nova network - network address already in use (no active instance)

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have a network which I want to delete.

The `nova net-list` command will return me this output:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| ID                                   | Label     | CIDR          |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 28b10eb4-88ae-46c4-802b-90456ffbd38e | intra-net | 10.0.0.128/25 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

If I type `nova net-delete 28b10eb4-88ae-46c4-802b-90456ffbd38e` the output will be:

```
ERROR (Conflict): Network 4 is still in use. (HTTP 409) (Request-ID: req-d4095852-3412-4c2b-a236-b272e221868c)
```

I have no instances created now (I terminated all of them). What else can use this network?

This is stacktrace found in /var/log/nova/nova-network.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/conductor/manager.py", line 400, in _object_dispatch
    return getattr(target, method)(context, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/objects/base.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return fn(self, ctxt, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/objects/network.py", line 179, in destroy
    db.network_delete_safe(context, self.id)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/api.py", line 961, in network_delete_safe
    return IMPL.network_delete_safe(context, network_id)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 125, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 2634, in network_delete_safe
    raise exception.NetworkInUse(network_id=network_id)
```

I have nova-legacy, not nova-network with neutron.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
netstat -tapnu | grep 10.0.0 network
```

If you are using a flat network with the dhcp option then most likely `dnsmasq` still holds those ip addresses in compute.

Look at the compute network logs.